# React: Session storage not storing images

Tags: reactjs, image, session-storage

I am trying to store the profile image of a user in the session storage (along with other information). I am sure I do not want local storage since I want the info to clear for new tabs.

Something goes wrong and I do not get to store the image successfully.

To store the image I use the `window.sessionStorage.setItem('profile_image', profile_image)` method.

The main component of the app sets it's state like this in the constructor:

`this.state = {`

`profile_image: window.sessionStorage.getItem('profile_image') || 'pending'`

`}`

This also happens for other variables, but not for some strings which get stored successfuly. I am lost...

Comment: Can you see item 'profile_image' actually stored in a session storage? I mean by exploring developer's console "Application" tab in Chrome? What is the value stored there?

Comment: I am with firefox. Application is empty and so is storage.

Comment: I just switched to chrome and same happens.

Comment: This basically means that problem isn't in reading value from storage but with putting it there. Can you please paste here code which saves value to storage? I mean, whole component containing `window.sessionStorage.setItem('profile_image', profile_image)` line

Comment: Forgive my late notice. Indeed, Andrew, it was a bugged if that never led to the set item method. Thing solved. For any lost reader like me, storing an image should not give any trouble.